# VBA Splitting a String into multiple cells when it has variable Delimiters

Tags: excel, vba, delimiter

If I have the below info all contained in a single cell and I want to split it into separate cells.  I understand how to use the space as a delimiter but in this case, the name also has spaces and I want the name to stay together in a single cell.  To further complicate the matter, the name is not always just first and last, it can also include middle so is not always a standard two names.

```
2172571122  Jane Doe 3143332222 John Doe

2172242237 Mary Mixer 2223334444 Mike M Martin
```

Want it to end up looking like this:

```
Cell 1 = 2172242237 
Cell 2 = Mary Mixer 
Cell 3 = 2223334444 
Cell 4 = Mike M Martin
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim strToSplit As String, strImport As String
    Dim arrwords As Variant
    Dim i As Long, counter As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        strToSplit = .Range("A1").Value
        arrwords = Split(strToSplit, " ")

        counter = 1

        For i = LBound(arrwords) To UBound(arrwords)

            If IsNumeric(arrwords(i)) = True Then
                strImport = arrwords(i)
                .Cells(3, counter).Value = strImport
                counter = counter + 1
            ElseIf Not IsNumeric(arrwords(i)) = True Then
                If Not IsNumeric(.Cells(3, counter - 1).Value) Then
                    strImport = .Cells(3, counter - 1) & " " & arrwords(i)
                    .Cells(3, counter - 1).Value = strImport
                    counter = counter
                Else
                    strImport = arrwords(i)
                    .Cells(3, counter).Value = strImport
                    counter = counter + 1
                End If
            End If

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results look like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This regex based function alternates each split between numbers and text (words).

```
Option Explicit

Function customSplit(str As String, _
                     Optional ndx As Integer = 1) As Variant

    Static rgx As Object, cmat As Object

    Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        If CBool(ndx Mod 2) Then
            .Pattern = "[0-9]{10}"
            ndx = (ndx + 1) \ 2
        Else
            .Pattern = "[A-Z]{1,9}\s[A-Z]{1,9}[\s[A-Z]{1,9}]?"
            ndx = ndx \ 2
        End If
        If .test(str) Then
            Set cmat = .Execute(str)
            If ndx <= cmat.Count Then
                customSplit = cmat.Item(ndx - 1)
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a few ideas on what you could do.

1)  Read a Line

Do a `split(line, " ")` and loop through the indecies while performing a `isNumeric()` on each split value.  If not, then add to a string Array() and set a flag to true.

Then, if isnumeric then, expect another name and set flag to true.

2)  Read a line.

Then, loop through each character performing an `isnumeric` and if not then add that character to a string Array() and set flag until `isnumeric` again, etc....

I hope that helps or at least gets you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Additional variant to posted already:

```
Sub ZZZ()
    Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim num$, cl As Range, data As Range, key, x
    Dim Result As Worksheet
    Set data = Range([A1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    For Each cl In data
        x = "": num = "":
        For Each x In Split(cl, " ")
            If IsNumeric(x) Then
                num = x
                dic.Add x, ""
            ElseIf x <> "" And num <> "" Then
                dic(num) = Trim(dic(num) & " " & x)
            End If
        Next x
    Next cl
    Set Result = Worksheets.Add
    With Result
        .Name = "Result " & Replace(Now, ":", "-")
        x = 1
        For Each key In dic
            .Cells(x, "A").Value2 = key
            .Cells(x, "B").Value2 = dic(key)
            x = x + 1
        Next key
        .Columns("A:B").AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

*test:*
[image]